# Formating a new table using python. Punch in and Punch out employee data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a list of employee punch date:

[image: TABLE 1]

that needs to be formatted into a different table LIKE:
[image: NEW FORMAT]

each new row has to be a new date. I have gotten started with variables, however I am failing at iterating through the columns to get the IN and OUT times. A little guidance would be appreciate for a beginner.

Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("sample_file.csv")

# save unique employee in array
employeeID = file['EMP ID'].unique()
dates = file['PUNCH DATE'].unique()
punchTimes = []

# print(employeeID)
# print(dates)

# print(file)

for employeeID, dates in file:
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you'll want to do two mutually exclusive filters then join on a pk. if you copy/paste the sample data I'll code it up -- never mind, I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### method 01

- [merge, join, concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'IN',   '4/1/22',   '3:56:00 AM'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'OUT',  '4/1/22',   '##########'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'IN',   '4/1/22',   '3:54:00 PM'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'OUT',  '4/1/22',   '8:02:00 PM'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'IN',   '4/2/22',   '3:57:00 AM'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'OUT',  '4/2/22',   '##########'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'IN',   '4/2/22',   '3:56:00 PM'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'OUT',  '4/2/22',   '8:01:00 PM'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'IN',   '4/3/22',   '3:55:00 AM'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'OUT',  '4/3/22',   '##########'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'IN',   '4/3/22',   '3:57:00 PM'],
['MCDONALD',    123987, 'OUT',  '4/3/22',   '8:00:00 PM']]

pks = ['EMP NAME','EMP ID','PUNCH DATE']
cols = ['EMP NAME', 'EMP ID',   'PUNCH TYPE',   'PUNCH DATE',   'PUNCH TIME']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = cols

def merge_dfs(left,right):
    df = pd.merge(left,right,how='outer',on=pks)
    return df


left = df.loc[df['PUNCH TYPE']=='IN']
l1 = left.drop_duplicates(subset=pks, keep='first')
l2 = left.drop_duplicates(subset=pks, keep='last')

right = df.loc[df['PUNCH TYPE']=='OUT']
r1 = right.drop_duplicates(subset=pks, keep='first')
r2 = right.drop_duplicates(subset=pks, keep='last')

tmp1 = merge_dfs(l1,r1)
tmp2 = merge_dfs(l2,r2)
final = merge_dfs(tmp1,tmp2)
```

### output

```
    EMP NAME    EMP ID  PUNCH TYPE_x_x  PUNCH DATE  PUNCH TIME_x_x  PUNCH TYPE_y_x  PUNCH TIME_y_x  PUNCH TYPE_x_y  PUNCH TIME_x_y  PUNCH TYPE_y_y  PUNCH TIME_y_y
0   MCDONALD    123987  IN  4/1/22  3:56:00 AM  OUT ##########  IN  3:54:00 PM  OUT 8:02:00 PM
1   MCDONALD    123987  IN  4/2/22  3:57:00 AM  OUT ##########  IN  3:56:00 PM  OUT 8:01:00 PM
2   MCDONALD    123987  IN  4/3/22  3:55:00 AM  OUT ##########  IN  3:57:00 PM  OUT 8:00:00 PM
```

[image: output]

### method 02

- [df.pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot)
- I'll code this up later when I have time

### aside

- since your question was specifically about iteration through a dataframe I'll note that the apply lambda patter is useful if you need to implement a custom function

```py
def funk(x):
    # do something
    pass

df.colum_name.apply(lambda x: funk(x))
```

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you so much... one more question, if I wanted to group them by date as well. How would I do that?

Comment: yep, I just reread your question and saw that -- editing now